# How to design paths for sub-resource within sub-resource in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am a complete beginner who is learning to build a RESTful web service. I would like to know how to set the path for sub resource within sub resource in JAX-RS.

I have three resources: profile, message and comment.
I would like my URLs to be as follows.

For profiles

```
 /profiles
```

For Messages

```
/profiles/{profileName}/messages
```

For Comments

```
/profiles/{profileName}/messages/{messageId}/comments
```

My resources have paths as follows.

> Profile Resource

```
@Path("/profiles")
public class ProfileResource {

    @Path("/{profileName}/messages")
    public MessageResource getMessageResource() {
        return new MessageResource();
    }

}
```

> Message Resource

```
@Path("/")
public class MessageResource {
    @Path("/{messageId}/comments")
    public CommentResource getCommentResource() {
        return new CommentResource();
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message addMessage(@PathParam("profileName") String profileName, Message message){
        return messageService.addMessage(profileName, message);
    }   
}
```

> Comment Resource

```
@Path("/")
public class CommentResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Comment postComment(@PathParam("messageId") long messageId, Comment comment) {
         return commentService.addComment(messageId, comment);
    }

}
```

But I get the following error,

```
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/messenger] threw 
load() exception org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: 
Validation of the  application resource model has failed during application 
initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST
  and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at 
Java  methods public sokkalingam.restapi.messenger.model.Message 
sokkalingam.restapi.messenger.resources.MessageResource.addMessage(java.lang.Strin
 g,sokkalingam.restapi.messenger.model.Message) and public 
sokkalingam.restapi.messenger.model.Comment 
sokkalingam.restapi.messenger.resources.CommentResource.postComment(long,sokkaling
 am.restapi.messenger.model.Comment) at matching regular expression /. These two 
 methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their 
 invocation as a resource methods will always fail.;
```

Questions:

1. How should I set my paths for my sub resources?
2. What is a better way to do sub resource within sub resource? Is it
   common to do sub-resource within sub-resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I set my paths for my sub resources?

Get rid of the `@Path` on the Sub-resource classes. When the class is annotated with path, it is being added as root resource to the Jersey app. So you have a bunch of resources mapped to `/`, which is giving the error, as there are multiple `@POST` (with same `@Consumes` and `@Produces`) mapped to the same path

With sub-resource classes, you don't need the `@Path`. It will be ignored, as far as the sub-resource path is concerned.

> What is a better way to do sub resource within sub resource? Is it common to do sub-resource within sub-resource?

I don't see any problem with what you are doing.